# Handling non.numeric values in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, numeric

I have a huge matrix of approximately 39000 rows and almost 80 columns. In R I am getting an error which says:

> Error in matrix(1, nrow = n, ncol = 1) : non-numeric matrix extent

When I did `typeof(matrix)` it gave me "double". Is there any way to find out what and where the problem is and any solution to the error?

Comment: Could you post a snippet of code showing how you assign your `n` and create your matrix? It looks like `n` isn't an integer, perhaps.

Comment: You're saying you have pain. We would like to know where it hurts and how it hurts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`n` in this call `matrix(1, nrow = n, ncol = 1)` is not numeric. You can replicate this with:

```
> matrix(1, nrow = "foo", ncol = 1)
Error in matrix(1, nrow = "foo", ncol = 1) : non-numeric matrix extent
```

So now you need to show the code you used to generate that error.